# Get FirstName + LastName from Yahoo OpenId using DotnetOpenAuth

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetopenauth

Using DotnetOpenAuth, I can get FirstName + LastName from Google OpenID like this using:

```
var fetch = new FetchRequest();

fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First);
fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);
```

But with Yahoo OpenId, FirstName and LastName `= null`

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName` to see if Yahoo! responds to that, but if not, then this is just one of those differences between Providers and Yahoo may not support everything you want.  This isn't a DotNetOpenAuth-specific thing.  It's a Yahoo thing.